# What would the EU referendum mean for me if I wanted to move back to the UK?

Tags: us-citizens, uk-visa, italian-citizens

I was born in the US and I have both US and Italian passports. I moved to the UK at the age of 13 and lived, studied and worked there for 9 years. I went to university in the UK, and moved back to the US exactly a year ago. I have been wanting to move back to the UK at some point in the near future - I don't know if this will be possible if the UK decides to leave the EU. Does anyone know what this would mean for me if I wanted to move back there, as I still have my university loan to pay back among other things.

Thanks